# ¿Qué hacer para redistribuir un programa hecho en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He acabado mi proyecto final del curso básico de programación, y necesito hacer correr mi programa hecho en `Python 3.6` en cualquier computadora que no tenga el lenguaje instalado, y no quiero instalarlo, mi tutor quiere darle doble `click` y que corra, y yo también quiero lograr eso.

En `QT` puedo usar un framework installer y con un simple comando, me detecta todas las librerías para hacer correr mi programa de forma dinámica, así que mi pregunta es sobre que tengo que hacer y aprender para redistribuir mi programa ya sea en `Linux Ubuntu`, `macOS` o `Windows`, que no tengan Python instalado.

PS. Las únicas librerías que uso son `random` y `pygame`

Answer (score 1):

Hay aplicaciones que hacen eso, como [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) y [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (esta ultima solo para Windows).

Si estás en Linux, normalmente no hace falta hacer nada, porque prácticamente todos los Linux incluyen Python. Basta con hacerlo ejecutable y agregar la línea 
`#!/usr/bin/env python` al principio (y cuidar que los saltos de línea sean Linux).